# can't call jConfirm script via c# code

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, alerts, jconfirm

I have to call a jConfirm function (jquery alert library) via c# programmatically.
I include the .js library in the master page of my site like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
            src='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js") %>'></script>
```

...and call the method via c# in this way:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "alert", @"
   <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript""> 
      jConfirm('Are you sure?', 'title', function(answer) {
                if (answer)
                    alert('ok');
                else
                    alert('ko');

      }); return false;
    </script>");
```

But it does not work... if i call in the same way for example a jAlert function everything goes fine, so i don't think is an import problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded the solution... it was a really naive reason!

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js") %>'></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
    src='<%# Page.ResolveClientUrl("/Scripts/jquery.alerts.js") %>'></script>
```

It seems that with the charachter '~' in the relative path this script does not work... without it goes fine.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside a function

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(System.Web.UI.Page), "alert", @"
   <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript""> 
    function FooAlert(){
      jConfirm('Are you sure?', 'title', function(answer) {
                if (answer)
                    alert('ok');
                else
                    alert('ko');

      }); return false;
    }
    </script>");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It still doesn't work. I noticed that it goes fine only with Chrome and the problem is in IE and Firefox but i have not been able to solve it yet.